# ThreeJS Add position offset to Matrix4 while chaining methodes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a ThreeJS Matrix4 containing the position of an element. I also have a second Matrix4 containing an offset (which I can get using `new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(offsetMatrix4)`). I would now like to add this offset on to the position of my first Matrix 4. The way I am currently doing so is:

```
baseMatrix4.setPosition(new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(baseMatrix4).add(new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(offsetMatrix4)))
```

The problem here is that I have to access baseMatrix4 inside the method, which prevents me from chaining it with previous method's, since baseMatrix4 would be undefined or outdated.

Do you have ideas for better ways to solve this while allowing chaining?

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, why do they have to be chained? It would be so easy if you allowed yourself to take up a few extra lines of code, why do you need everything in a single statement?

```
var basePos = new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(baseMatrix4);
var offsetPos = new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(offsetMatrix4);
baseMatrix4.setPosition(basePos.add(offsetPos));
```

#### Edit:

If you don't want to create any `Vector3`s, you could just modify the matrix directly, by copying [the behavior of `Vector3.setFromMatrixPosition()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Vector3.js#L626)

```
b = baseMatrix4.elements;
o = offsetMatrix4.elements;
b[12] = b[12] + o[12];
b[13] = b[13] + o[13];
b[14] = b[14] + o[14];
```

... alternatively you could use the `+=` operator if you prefer.

Comment: my code currently has no variable basePos, ist just an arrow function which returns a newly created object. I would like to avoid creating unnecessary variables

Comment: I see. I just added an alternative version to my answer that doesn't require you create any `Vector3`s.

Comment: thats what I did first, then I changed it to a function `[12, 13, 14].forEach(i => b[i] += o[i])` and right now I am just doing this somewhere else entirely